# to work other method before constructor work even called object initialization in java

Tags: java, constructor

I want to ask a question about java constructor.

Example,i have "A" class and "B" class and i created constructor in "b" class. In normal way, when i create "b" class object in main method of "a" class, class "b" constructor will automatically work. So, my question is when I create b class object in "a" class,i want to work other functions first before working constructor.
So what should i do?

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}

public class B {
    public B() {
        System.out.print("Hello Constructor");
    }

    public void m() {
        System.out.print("Hello Method");
    }
}
```

Normally :: Output :: **Hello Constructor**
                      **Hello Method**

i want this Output :: **Hello Method** **Hello Constructor**

Can be? Sorry for my bad English...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the constructor of B, call the method M. your question is a tad confusing, but if I understand you correctly, this is what you want.

```
public class A{
public static void main(String[] args){
    B bb=new B();
}

public class B{
public B(){
    M();
    System.out.print("Hello Constructor");
}
public void M(){
    System.out.print("Hello Method");
}
```

Comment: Actually ,i don't want to call method from constructor andI want to output method first before constructor . Sorry about my confusing question.

Comment: That's not possible. In Java, when you create an instance of a class, as with B bb=new B();, you are calling the constructor method. You cannot create an instance of a class without calling the constructor first.

Answer (score 0):

actually you can't do it with your thinking way(or i don't know a way for it) but you can try this:

```
public class A {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
    }
}

public class B {
    public B() {
        //write what are you wanting to do like m(); for this exapmle
        System.out.print("Hello Constructor");
    }

    public void m() {
        System.out.print("Hello Method");
    }
}
```

its simple trick but it wokrs.By the way you can try it without constructor like initializing your variables with another method:

```
public class A{
public static void main(String[] args){
    B bb=new B();
    bb.m();
    bb.b();
}

public class B{
public void b(){
    System.out.print("Hello Constructor");
}
public void m(){
    System.out.print("Hello Method");
}
```